# how to disable future months in p-calendar?

Tags: angular, primeng, monthcalendar

I want to disable  future months and display only current month while selecting in UI, I am using p-calendar.

```html
<p-calendar appendTo="body" class="SharesTblCalendar" name="closeDate" 
            [(ngModel)]="note.closeDate" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true"
            [yearRange]="yearRange" 
</p-calendar>
```

this is the code I am using but couldnot resctric it from taking  month

Comment: What are you using? PrimeFaces or PrimeNG?

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: i am using primeNG

Comment: calendar should display current month and previous months (eg: as of today it should show only jan and feb ,march->december should be disable)

Comment: Have you tried to use `maxDate` option ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use maxDate to restrict calendar

```
 <p-calendar appendTo="body" class="SharesTblCalendar" name="closeDate" 
            [(ngModel)]="note.closeDate" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" 
            [yearRange]="yearRange"  [maxDate]="maxDate"
</p-calendar>


let today = new Date();
let month = today.getMonth();
this.maxDate = new Date();
this.maxDate.setMonth(month);
```